# NullPointer at viewPager

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have recently gotten back to developing the app i was working on and encountered a problem when trying to run it. The app has worked fine when run before so I am a little puzzled about this.

Log cat:

```
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{simcas.fartberegneren/simcas.fartberegneren.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at simcas.fartberegneren.MyAdapter.<init>(MyAdapter.java:38)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at simcas.fartberegneren.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
07-30 12:07:53.119: E/AndroidRuntime(8070):     ... 11 more
```

view_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private final Context mContext;
private final ActionBar mActionBar;
private final ViewPager mViewPager;
private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

static final class TabInfo {
    private final Class<?> clss;
    private final Bundle args;

    TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
        clss = _class;
        args = _args;
    }
}

public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    mContext = activity;
    mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    mViewPager = pager;
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this); // This is line 38 causing the nullpointer
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

static Context context;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private ViewPager myViewPager;

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    myViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    final ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, myViewPager); // This is line 32 
    myAdapter.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.menu_speed), SpeedZonesFragment.class, null);
    myAdapter.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.menu_dist), DistanceFragment.class, null);
    myAdapter.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(R.string.menu_fuel), FuelConsumptionFragment.class, null);
```

What am I missing here?

It should be noted that the code havent changed since i successfully ran it on my device half a year ago.

EDIT:

It seems, that even though I add some code, the nullpointer is still from the same two lines, despite the line has changed! What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor `public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager)` is being called with a null `pager`.

Make a break point here:

```
myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

Check if it is returning your pager object and check the xml `view_pager.xml` for the pager ID make sure it is `view_pager`.

EDIT: I saw your posted XML, please make sure of it's name `view_pager.xml` because you didn't post that.

Comment: I have edited the name in. The view_pager is in the R.id and the name view_pager.xml is the correct name for the xml file. I have added a breakpoint but how do i check if it returns my pager?

Comment: Even when i add lines of code, the nullpointer still points towards line 32 i MainActivity and 38 in MyAdapter, so - what is going on?

Comment: WHat's going on is that findViewById is not finding the view pager

Comment: And the cause can be that the value i feed is not correct but I have double checked that it is the correct value in both MyAdapter and MainActivity along with view_pager.xml as it is in R.Layout.

Comment: it's a long shot but try cleaning the project

Comment: That was my first "go-to" but the thing is, since upgrading to the new android API and sdk in eclipse i can no longer clean my android project?

Comment: upload the project somewhere, say github.com

Answer (score 1):

try this:- Put try catch block where you are setting the Adapter. And If possible take a static variable in Main Activity.

```
public static int selectedTab;
```

and in the

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    selectedTab = tab.getPosition();
    Log.d("Selected Tab is", ">" + selectedTab);
}
```

and the place where you are setting adapter, put this type of code. In my case I have 7 tabs and each has view pager. So on the 4th tab I put this code which ignore the Null pointer exception. Actually It happens because, if on the first tab the data is not come, and we move on the 4th or 5th tab and after that if data will come on first tab. Then we get the NullPointer Exception. Sorry for my english, I hope you will understand.

```
if (MainActivity.selectedTab == 0 || MainActivity.selectedTab == 1|| MainActivity.selectedTab == 2
                || MainActivity.selectedTab == 6) {
        } else {
            try {
                adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.row_gallery, mGridArray);
                mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The thing is, that the above code I have supplied have worked and has not been changed since.